# Is this a bug in NCAlgebra library?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, packages, ncalgebra

In course of my work with `NCAlgebra` package for Mathematica, http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/ , I encountered unexpected behavior of replacements. I am using Mathematica 8 with compatible version of NCAlgebra, 4.0.4.
I would like to rule out the possibility of botched installation of NCAlgebra, although on my computer it seems to pass all in-built tests.

I define two very similar transformation rules and an expression to use them on:

```
<<NC`    
<<NCAlgebra`
rule1 = b_ ** a_ :> -a ** b;
rule2 = HoldPattern[b_ ** a_] :> -a ** b;
expr = -x ** x ** y - y ** x;
```

Now I apply these rules using two different methods: `Substitute` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
expr /. rule1
SubstituteSingleReplace[expr, rule1]
expr /. rule2
SubstituteSingleReplace[expr, rule2]
  (*result*)
x ** y - x ** x ** y
x ** y + x ** x ** y
x ** y - x ** x ** y
x ** y - x ** x ** y
```

Nothing special, `Substitute` and `ReplaceAll` are expected to work a little differently.

```
b=2;
rule1
expr /. rule1
SubstituteSingleReplace[expr, rule1]
expr /. rule2
SubstituteSingleReplace[expr, rule2]
```

Now things become strange. `rule1` now looks differently - non-commutative multiplication `**` is replaced by commutative product `Times`:

```
b_ a_ :> -a ** b
```

The results of replacements look really weird (note that the change in result of `ReplaceAll` is likely due to change of the rule)

```
y ** x + x ** x ** y
-2 y ** x - 2 x ** x ** y
x ** y - x ** x ** y
2 x - x ** x ** y
```

Are the inner workings of the pattern are affected by the definitions of global variables? I thought previosly that this behavior can be negated by using `HoldPattern[_]`, but with this example it is proved ineffective.

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: I will say that some of this looks like very unhealthy behavior. Since `rule1` changed from `NoncommutativeMultiply` to `Times` I would guess that the symbol `b` is leaking somewhere in such a way that `rule1` was seen as scalar-(nc-)times-something` and that allowed the type of product to change to ordinary `Times`. But that's just a vague guess and this is something the package authors would need to investigate.

Comment: I will be very thankful if someone tested this independently; for now I am not entirely sure if this is a bug of `NCAlgebra` or a consequence of external factors.

Comment: I do not have `NCAlgebra` but I can say that testing the parts that do not rely on that package gave different results from what you showed.

Comment: It might be a good idea to contact the package author directly (and also point them to this thread).

Comment: I am removing the `bugs` tag because the bug appears to be in the package and not Mathematica itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try the newest version of **NCAlgebra**:

https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC

In version 5.0.0, `Substitute` and `Transform` were replaced by the more reliable `NCReplace`, `NCReplaceAll`, and `NCReplaceRepeated`. These closely mirror the corresponding Mathematica `Replace` commands. In your example:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
rule1 = b_ ** a_ :> -a ** b;
rule2 = HoldPattern[b_ ** a_] :> -a ** b;
rule3 = b_ ** a_ -> -a ** b;
expr = -x ** x ** y - y ** x
```

all three substitutions:

```
NCReplaceAll[expr, rule1]
NCReplaceAll[expr, rule2]
NCReplaceAll[expr, rule3]
```

result in:

> x ** y + x ** y ** x

Be careful with such rules though as you are relying on Mathematica's pattern matching to select which of the two "sides" of `x**x**y` get swapped. For example:

```
expr = -y ** x ** z - y ** x
NCReplaceAll[expr, rule1]
```

results in

> x ** y + x ** z ** y

not

> x ** y + z ** y ** x

Your rule also generates an infinite recursion if used with `NCReplaceRepeated`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two related bugs.  `SubstituteSingleReplace` calls `RulesComplement` to construct a list of rules and their opposites (so in your case `b_ ** a_ :> -a ** b` and `-b_ ** a_ :> a ** b`).  Unfortunately, the function incorrectly uses `Rule` when given a `RuleDelayed` (my `In[1]` was loading the package):

```
In[2]:= RulesComplement[b_ ** a_ :> -a ** b]
Out[2]= {b_ ** a_ :> -a ** b, -b_ ** a_ -> a ** b}
```

This is not trivial to fix.  One option without touching the package is to patch the `DownValues` of `RulesComplement`:

```
DownValues[RulesComplement] = (DownValues[RulesComplement] /.
   Which[pre___, lhs_ === RuleDelayed, Rule[a_, -#1[[2]]], post___] :>
   Which[pre,
     lhs === RuleDelayed, 
     RuleDelayed[a, Evaluate[Extract[#1, {2}, Function[{x}, Unevaluated[-x], HoldAll]]]], 
     post])
```

This code finds the `Which` statement in the definition of `RulesComplement`, specifically the clause treating `RuleDelayed`, and essentially replaces `Rule` by `RuleDelayed`.  This is complicated by the fact that we want the part `#1[[2]]` (right-hand side of the rule) to be extracted but not further evaluated.

The second bug is in `SubstituteSingleReplace` itself: it splits each rule into left-hand side and right-hand side and evaluates both.  This is done in order to construct a more general rule that will match `NonCommutativeMultiply` with more arguments.

Instead of fixing it, I suggest using the following code (after you fix `RulesComplement`) instead of `SubstituteSingleReplace`.

```
With[{pre = Unique[], post = Unique[]},
  SetNonCommutative[pre, post];
  mySubstituteSingleReplace[expr_, rules_] :=
    expr /.
      (RulesComplement[Flatten[{rules}]] /.
        (f : Rule | RuleDelayed)[lhs_, rhs_] :> 
        f[pre___ ** lhs ** post___, pre ** rhs ** post])
]
```

First find the rules with their opposites, then construct rules which allow additional factors in the `NonCommutativeMultiply`, namely rules of the form `pre___ ** lhs ** post___ :> pre ** rhs ** post`.  This is straightforward for `RuleDelayed`, but for `Rule` we have to be careful that the right-hand side of the new rule is evaluated and `pre` and `post` could have values.  This is the reason for using `Unique[]`.  The code does not deal correctly with `HoldPattern`, so your `rule2` isn't supported, sorry.